# Types distribute on first generic but not second

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

`test0` Does not ditribute as the second type is a union while `test1` ditribute as expected.

How can I have an union ditributed in any case ?

```
type Type<A extends number, B extends number> = A extends B ? 'eq' : 'neq'

type test0 = Type<2, 2 | 3> // "eq"         (but expected "eq" | "neq")
type test1 = Type<2 | 3, 2> // "eq" | "neq" (as expected)
```

Link to [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYKozN)

Comment: Only the "checked type" (in this case `A`) is distributed over the union as per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types). That seems entirely reasonable. Otherwise, how would you expect `Type<2 | 3, 2 | 3>` to be instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your type like this

```js
type Type<A extends number, B extends number> = 
  | (A extends B ? 'eq' : 'neq')
  | (Exclude<B, A> extends never ? never : 'neq')
```

[TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEB4CCUIA9gQHYBMDOUWArgLYBGEATgDRQBCqG2+hpFlAfFALxQAUKdJlwEGAfigByCAEdJUAFxSssyQEooAH34BRNAGMANkRyI6tJFyHMCKgG5UoE+46WSVctQCgvoSFEw8YAAGHlh4BAAmWkitKABmLgB6JKgAIlk0qGycnL4yImBGSH1MHHTMrQACtI807xTc7IA9MR8-aEDgAEYwuEgouPiY5NSMmSzNGrr+AEMCdBKyhtSm1vb4AIgg2N5+xGioSI4vRrW2302u+L6Iw8TT1dz1y-8ugBZbgeGjk7PntpAA)